# Vue Transition does not apply the transition classes

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a simple VueJS project, and when I add some transitions, nothing works. I copied the example from the Vue documentation, but it still doesn't work.

This is my `App.vue` file

```js
<script setup>
import { ref } from "vue";

const show = ref(true);
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="show = !show">Toggle Slide + Fade</button>
  <Transition name="slide-right" appear>
    <div v-if="show">hello</div>
    <div v-else>world</div>
  </Transition>
</template>

<style>
.slide-right-enter-active {
  transition: all 5s ease-out;
}

.slide-right-leave-active {
  transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(1, 0.5, 0.8, 1);
}

.slide-right-enter-from,
.slide-right-leave-to {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

When I click on the toggle button, the text below will change. However, no transition classes (like slide-right-enter-active, slide-right-leave-active, ...) are applied.

**Update:**

> I found that it only happens in MS Edge (dev). I tried it on another browser, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this codebox - https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-platform-y48xzt?file=/src/App.vue

This works fine.

Comment: Oh, I tried it on Windows, and everything works fine, but it still doesn't work on Ubuntu. I really don't know why. :(